# Rspec Test Won't Pass using assigns()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, controller

Here is my current users_controller_spec.rb file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views
  .
  .
  .
  describe "success" do

   before(:each) do
    @attr = { :name => "New User", :email => "user@example.com",
              :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar" }
  end

  it "should create a user" do
    lambda do
      post :create, :user => @attr
    end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "should redirect to the user show page" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    response.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
   end
  end
 end
end
```

When I run this I get the following:

```
 Failures:

1) UsersController POST 'create' success should redirect to the user show page
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(user_path(user))
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Which leads me to believe that :user isn't an actual object. How can I test this and how can I change :user into an object that user_path understands.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATED:**

```
def create
  @title = "Sign up"
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, :notice => "Signed Up!"
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render "new"
  end
end
```

When I run the following:

```
it "should redirect to the user show page" do
  post :create, :user => @attr
  user = assigns(:user)
  user.should_not be_blank
  puts "user errors are: #{user.errors.full_messages.inspect}" unless user.is_valid?
  user.should be_valid
  response.should redirect_to(user_path(user))
end
```

I get:

```
1) UsersController POST 'create' success should redirect to the user show page
     Failure/Error: user.should_not be_blank
       expected blank? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:94:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo

```
response.should redirect_to(user_path(:user))
```

should be

```
response.should redirect_to(user_path(user))
```

Edit:
Try checking that the user is valid with:

```
it "should redirect to the user show page" do
  post :create, :user => @attr
  user = assigns(:user)
  user.should_not be_blank
  puts "user errors are: #{user.errors.full_messages.inspect}" unless user.is_valid?
  user.should be_valid
  response.should redirect_to(user_path(user))
end
```

I know it works on the previous test case... but still worth checking extensively at least once here. You can remove all that guff when you're certain.

Comment: I then get the following error: ` undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_2:0x007f92e74f0a20>`. I'm not sure if your suggestion brings me closer or further away from getting it working.

Comment: Please see updated code above, I cleaned it up and removed my test code.

Comment: is it still breaking? If so, I've got a coupe more suggestions in answer above.

Comment: ok... that's pretty odd. How about in your "create" action, do a `puts params[:user].inspect`

Comment: Do I put that in my controller or in my test? I put it in my controller, but I'm not sure where puts is putting it.

Comment: Put that in the controller - to see if you're actually getting a) to the create method and b) that it's actually getting the attributes you're passing in. You should see it in the rspec output (up where it's initially shown as either red/green, not at the bottom with the stacktrace)

Comment: Okay, I get something like: `{"name"=>"New User", "email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"foobar", "password_confirmation"=>"foobar"}` out of it. It hits that multiple times trying different tests.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `assigns` with brackets instead of parenthesis.

`assigns[:user]`

([*RSpec docs*](http://rspec.info/rails/writing/controllers.html))

---

**EDIT**

One pattern I always use when testing controller actions is to ensure that a variable required by the associated view(s) is assigned. For example,

```
it "should assign an @user variable" do
  post :create, :user => @attr
  assigns[:user].should_not be_nil
  assigns[:user].should be_kind_of(User)
end
```

Comment: I've kept them in as per the docs, but this still gives me the same error as above. Thank you for spotting that.

Comment: The spec "should create a user" is passing?

Comment: Yes, it is. Does that give you a clue to something else?

Comment: Try printing the errors on the user as @Taryn suggested before the should_not be_blank assertion. Are there errors on the user object?

Comment: I get `undefined method 'is_valid' ?for nil:NilClass` so what would cause my user to be nil?

Comment: I've posted my code above previously doesn't  `@user = User.new(params[:user])` assign a value to @user? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yeah, it does. What version of RSpec are you using? `gem list rspec`

Comment: That test passes when it should assign an @user variable.

Comment: I'm lost as to why it `should assign an @user variable` (which checks for assigns[:user] to not be nil) is passing, yet the spec directly after it returns nil for assigns[:user].

Comment: Alright. I'm learning Rails now, so I may have done something horribly wrong somewhere else. I'll just move on and maybe find it later as I build out more functionality. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that you have a redundant test in there. `assigns[:user].should be_kind_of(User)` tests `assigns[:user].should_not be_nil` already. You may as well lose the line `assigns[:user].should_not be_nil` in refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

In your test:

```
 it "should redirect to the user show page" do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    post :create, :user => @attr
    user = assigns(:user)
    response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
  end
```

Your `@attr` hash is different from @user. You are creating user with attributes of @attr, and asserting that it should redirect to @user show (which is different from one created). Change to:

```
 it "should redirect to the user show page" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    user = assigns(:user)
    response.should redirect_to(user_path(user))
  end
```

Comment: I'm aware that my @attr is different than my `@user`. I've cleaned up the code and removed the test code. Hopefully this clarifies. Still the same error though. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Have you tried: `response.assigns(:user).email.should == @attr[:email])` type of test. This is in case if you do POST to :create with @attr.